# Calculate distinct of a table column plus two static values using DAX

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

I have a tabular cube that I working on. I would like to get distinct values from "Column1" and then get two additional columns(to be created afresh) as static text one as "All" and other as "2020Q4".

Output would look like:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | All | 2020Q4 |
| BB | All | 2020Q4 |
| CC | All | 2020Q4 |
| DD | All | 2020Q4 |
| EE | All | 2020Q4 |

Any help is appreciated. So far I am able to get distinct but unable to get associated static values.

Answer (score 2):

Your can simplify the code:

```
EVALUATE
ADDCOLUMNS (
    DISTINCT ( TableName[Column1] ),
    "Column2", "All",
    "Column3", "2020Q4"
)
```

Comment: Thank you, yes it does look and function better!

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to do it as below:

```
 EVALUATE 
       Addcolumns( DISTINCT(Tblname[Column1]), "Column2", 
 SELECTCOLUMNS(Tblname, "Column2", SUBSTITUTE(Tblname[Column1], 
 Tblname[Column1], "All")),
 "Column3", SELECTCOLUMNS(Tblname, "Column3", SUBSTITUTE(Tblname[Column1], 
 Tblname[Column1], "2020Q4"))
 )
```